# Where to find Concrete Roman TTF/OTF fonts

Tags: fonts

This is not strictly a TeX-related question, but as `Concrete Roman` fonts were designed by DEK and distributed with TeX, I hope to find an answer here.

I'd like to use the `Concrete Roman` fonts on a website.  However, finding ttf/otf files on the internet isn't easy. Are they available in any modern (=possible to use as web fonts) format?  If so, what license are they available under?  On CTAN I could only find mf/tfm files (useless for web) and [Type 1](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm-super) files (same). Googling didn't help a lot, the Wikipedia page directed me to [this page with a non-working download link](https://cm-unicode.sourceforge.io/download.html), [this page](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/cmu-concrete) suggests that the fonts are available under the SIL Open Font License (which AFAIR is rather permissive), but the download link leads to some other font catalogue apparently not containing Concrete Roman at all...

Comment: See [cm-unicode](https://cm-unicode.sourceforge.io/index.html). Also available on ctan. But I do not dare to stand up for their quality.

Comment: @mickep: thanks, but the download link there doesn't work...

Comment: Ah, ok - I downloaded them from CTAN. Thanks, the Roman one looks good, but the italics one is a bit worse... Still, this is probably the best I can get...

Comment: Note that the Greek letters are different in different fonts.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis thanks for the info, though I'm sure I won't need them very often (in fact, probably (almost) never).

Answer (score 3):

Run in a terminal `luafindfont`:

```
voss@H-MacBook ~ % luafindfont concret
  No.          Filename Symbolic name                                                                    Path
   1.       cmunobi.otf  cmuconcrete    /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/
   2.       cmunobx.otf  cmuconcrete    /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/
   3.       cmunorm.otf  cmuconcrete    /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/
   4.       cmunoti.otf  cmuconcrete    /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/
   5. Concrete-Math.otf concretemath  /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/concmath-otf/
```

Comment: Looks promising, but... `bash: luafindfont: command not found`. What do I need for that? I have texlive 2018, I guess it's too old...?

Comment: Your TeX distribution should come with both `fc-match` and `luaotfload-tool --find="Concrete" --fuzzy`.

Comment: @mbork: yes 2018 is really old ...

Comment: @mbork: it is only one Lua script: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/luafindfont/scripts. and can easily be installed

Comment: @Davislor: `luaotfload-tool` is for users not really helpful: `luaotfload-tool --find="Concrete" --fuzzy
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "Concrete" not found.`

Comment: @user187802 Okay, you either need to do a more complex pattern or know that the family you're looking for is CMU Concrete.

Comment: `luaotfload-tool`. is good for the _internal_ `luatex` font handling, but _not_ for a user who wants to get informations about his fonts.

Answer (score 3):

[This web page](https://checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/) addresses your use case: a collection of Computer Modern fonts put together for the web.

[This more recent project](https://github.com/jarnosz/Concrete-LGC) may be off-topic for you but perhaps this variation of the Concrete font collection is worth a look.